# changed targetSdkVersion to 33 from 30 and now notifications are not coming up

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, android-manifest, android-permissions

I updated targetSdkVersion from 30 to 33 and notifications popup is not shown when the app is installed on the device

when the targetSdkVersion is 30 and when I install the app, the following popup shows up and when I click allow I do get notifications

[image]

when the targetSdkVersion is 33, I donot get the following popup when the app is installed.
I looked at https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission
and added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>` in manifest file.
still I do not get any prompt asking for permission for notifications.

I have code which checks if notification is enabled and it returns null cuz no prompt is shown.

```
private fun isNotificationsEnabled(): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val manager = oApp.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (!manager.areNotificationsEnabled()) {
            return false
        }
        val channels = manager.notificationChannels
        for (channel in channels) {
            if (channel.importance == NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE) {
                return false
            }
        }
        true
    } else {
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(oApp).areNotificationsEnabled()
    }
}
```

How can i force prompt or what else I need to do so user get this prompt on first install

thanks in advance
R

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#POST_NOTIFICATIONS), the new `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission is classified as a *dangerous* permission, which means you must manually request the permission from the user at runtime. The process for requesting a dangerous permission from the user is explained in [the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting). Best practices for dangerous permissions state that you should not request the permission until the point when the user requests the behavior that requires the permission.

Comment: as these are notifications as soon as they are logged in we will need this permission, so we can send push notifications.
is it okay to request this once they are logged in to the app

Comment: I think it’s okay. They only make that instruction under “best practices”, so I don’t think they enforce it, and anyway if your app needs to use something from the beginning I don’t think you’re violating what it suggests anyway. But this is all only my interpretation. I can’t guarantee how Google will treat it.